# Find the spectral basis of the following endomorphism

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, group-homomorphism

I have the following problem, I have to find the spectral basis ( I hope I am translating this correctly) for the following endomorphism ( homomorphism ):

$\ R^3 -> R^3 f(x,y,z)=( (x,6y,2z),(2y),(x,4y,2z)) $

I created the associated matrix and found the eigenvalues

$$
   \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 6 & 2 \\
   0 & 2 & 0 \\
   1 & 4 & 2 \\
   \end{bmatrix}
$$

I tried to find det(A-$\lambda$I)
    $$
   \begin{bmatrix}
   1-\lambda & 6 & 2 \\
   0 & 2-\lambda & 0 \\
   1 & 4 & 2-\lambda \\
   \end{bmatrix}
$$
And from this I found the roots of the eigenvalues as $\lambda=0,2,3$

Now I tried finding the basis by re-writing the matrices with every $\lambda$ value 
$$\lambda = 0$$
$$
   \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 6 & 2 \\
   0 & 2 & 0 \\
   1 & 4 & 2 \\
   \end{bmatrix}$$

The equivalent linear solution is :

$$
\begin{cases}
x+6y+2z=0\\
2y=0\\
x+4y+2z=0\\
\end{cases}
$$
Since $ y=0 $ I have attributed to z a parametric solution, and my result is:
$$
\begin{cases}
x=-2s\\
y=0\\
z=s\\
\end{cases}
$$
If I create a vector from that I get :
$$ s*\begin{pmatrix}
-2\\
0\\1\\ \end{pmatrix} $$
Doing the same calculations for 2 and 3 I get:
$$\lambda=3$$
$
\begin{bmatrix}
   -2 & 6 & 2 \\
   0 & -1 & 0 \\
   1 & 4 & -1 \\
   \end{bmatrix}$ 
$ \begin{cases}
-2x+2z=0\\
y=0\\
z=s\\
\end{cases}$ 
Vector:
$ s*\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\1\\ \end{pmatrix} $

$$\lambda=2$$
$
\begin{bmatrix}
   -1 & 6 & 2 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   1 & 4 & 0 \\
   \end{bmatrix}$ 
$ \begin{cases}
x=-4s\\
y=s\\
z=-5s\\
\end{cases}$ 
Vector:
$ s*\begin{pmatrix}
-4\\
1\\-5\\ \end{pmatrix} $

And so I find $ B_1=\{-2,0,1\}$ $ B_3=\{1,0,1\}$ that are correct basis for the endomorphism, however for $\lambda = 2$ I get the basis 
$ B_2=\{-4,1,-5\}$  that is exactly half of what I should get, I am unsure weather I have proceeded correctly, but seeing as I have 2/3 correct results, I don't know if it's something I'm doing wrong or I'm just going insane, I would appreciate some insight, thank you !

Comment: If $\mathbf v$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then so is $c\mathbf v$ for $c\ne0$. Unless there’s some convention in force for choosing particular eigenvectors over others, your answer is just as correct as the one you’re comparing against.

Comment: BTW, one can find the eigenvalues of this matrix by inspection. It obviously doesn’t have full rank, so one eigenvalue is $0$. If you add the first and last columns you get $(3,0,3)^T$, so $(1,0,1)^T$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $3$. The last eigenvalue you get “for free” because the sum of the eigenvalues is equal to the trace: $1+2+2-0-3=2$.

Comment: OMG I totally forgot about the first one, I was so concerned with the fact that the result wasn't exact with the textbook that I panicked, thank you sir. 
Also, good tip, how do I select you as best answer ?

Comment: I wrote my comment up as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answer is fine. If $\mathbf v$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then so is $c\mathbf v$ for $c\ne0$. Unless there’s some convention about which eigenvectors to choose out of all of the possibilities, your answer is just as correct as the one you’re comparing against.